# Unable to take character input in java

Tags: java

i am new to java and i want to take an input as follows:

**0 2 a**

I am able to take the integer input but unable to take the character input.

i am using following code

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int o = s.nextInt();
    if(o==0)
        {
             int l=s.nextInt();
             char c=s.next().charAt(0);
        }
```

Comment: does next.char(0) only take 1st letter from the input?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. Can you explain your problem a bit more.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine ([demo](http://ideone.com/3uWmco)).

Comment: Just dump the Scanner and save yourself headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May be Thats because the Scanner#nextInt method does not read the last
>   newline character of your input, and thus that newline is consumed in
>   the next call to Scanner#nextLine.

Fire a new Line after nextInt.

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int o = s.nextInt();
    s.nextLine();
        if(o==0)
            {
                 int l=s.nextInt();
s.nextLine();
                 char c=s.next().charAt(0);
            }
```

Comment: -1. The next call to `nextInt` will ignore any upcoming line breaks. There is no call to `nextLine` in the code. Mixing `nextLine` and `next` or `nextInt` is generally not a good idea exactly because of these ignored `nextLine` statements you have to use, but if you stick to one or the other, you should not have any problems, and these aren't necessary. A comment on the question links to the code in the question working fine.